# getting elements from an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having a problem with an arrayList in which I store member objects. I think it might be something to do with the way i've declared it. This is what I have so far

**Member Class**

```
package assignment;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Member {

private int memberID;
private String memberName;
private int memberAge;
private int numOfBooksLoaned;
private int penalties;

public Member(int memberID, String memberName, int memberAge, int numOfBooksLoaned, int penalties) {
    this.memberID = memberID;
    this.memberName = memberName;
    this.memberAge = memberAge;
    this.numOfBooksLoaned = numOfBooksLoaned;
    this.penalties = penalties;
}

public int getMemberID() {
        return memberID;
    }




    public void setMemberID(int memberID) {
        this.memberID = memberID;
    }




    public String getMemberName() {
        return memberName;
    }




    public void setMemberName(String memberName) {
        this.memberName = memberName;
    }




    public int getMemberAge() {
        return memberAge;
    }




    public void setMemberAge(int memberAge) {
        this.memberAge = memberAge;
    }




    public int getNumOfBooksLoaned() {
        return numOfBooksLoaned;
    }




    public void setNumOfBooksLoaned(int numOfBooksLoaned) {
        this.numOfBooksLoaned = numOfBooksLoaned;
    }




    public int getPenalties() {
        return penalties;
    }




    public void setPenalties(int penalties) {
        this.penalties = penalties;
    }




}
```

**MemberList class**

```
package assignment;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MemberList {

private ArrayList<Member> Members;

    public MemberList(ArrayList<Member> Members)
    {
        this.Members = Members;
    }

    public void addNewMember()
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean successful = false;
        int memberID;
        String memberName;
        int memberAge;

        do {

            System.out.println("/t/tCreate new member" + "/nPlease enter your full name: ");
            memberName = input.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < Members.size(); i++) {
                if (Members.get(i).getMemberName().equalsIgnoreCase(memberName)) {
                    System.out.println("This member name is already in use");
                } else {
                    successful = true;
                }

            }

        } while (successful == false);
```

The problem is just after the for loop in the if statement

```
if (Members.get(i).getMemberName().equalsIgnoreCase(memberName))
```

the error says that `getMemberName()` is undefined for type `Member`.
Any ideas?

I have used this exact same identical way of using an arrayList and it works fine but it isn't working now for some reason.

Comment: Could you post the entire stackTrace please and also the entire Member class.

Comment: how to I post the entire stackTrace?

Comment: Copy paste the console. :)

Comment: After I ran the program the error went away and now it works fine? I'm now sure how that happened :) Thanks anyway for your help  Yassin Hajaj :D

Comment: LOL no problem even if I did not do much :)

Answer (score -1):

try to use a foreach loop in this way

```
for (Member m : Members) {
    if (m.getMemberName().equalsIgnoreCase(memberName)) {
        System.out.println("This member name is already in use");
    } else {
        successful = true;
    }
}
```

Another thing, is discouraged to use Capital letter at first letter in class members in Java, define the list as

```
private ArrayList<Member> members;
```